# Search problem - are there really only two jobs within 100 km of Massachusetts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

It seems like there are a lot of jobs missing from the search results. If you look under the "search companies" tab, there are plenty with jobs available, but those jobs don't show up in the search. This is also a problem in Vermont.

[image]

The URL is https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=Massachusetts%2C+United+States&d=20&u=Km - Accessing it from the Caribbean.

Comment: I see 132 jobs.   But the machine doesn't think I live in Trinidad.

Comment: When I view that URL, I see 31 listings

Comment: Well, I do live in Trinidad and it doesn't work from my home or office computer. I used to see lots of jobs, but its been like this since around the start of the year.

Comment: New York City lists 14 jobs. I'm thinking there should be more?

Comment: Massachusetts and Vermont don't use km to measure distance. Try searching for jobs within 60 miles.

Comment: Good suggestion. Kilometers is the only option I see on my user interface, However, I edited the URL and changed "Km" to "Mi", at which point it showed me a bunch of jobs. It even showed them to me after I switched back to Km (so they must be cashed someplace.) However, I tried to replicate the Km to Mi switch again in a browser that was not logged in, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is hiding of some offers location or reputation based?

Comment: Huh, that's actually pretty weird that it makes a difference. I was just trying to be silly.

Comment: Same, I see two jobs in Atlanta and just statistically speaking I know there has to be more than that

Comment: We found a bug that resulted in incorrect geocoding for some users home locations. The bug has been fixed for location updates, but we still need to backfill all existing affected users and fix their corrupted data. Should be done by the end of the day.

Answer (score -15):

Your job preferences had not been synced correctly.

The problem should now be fixed, and you should see more results.

Thank you for your report!

**Update:** There were additional geocoding issues which have been fixed as well.

Comment: Wait, what? How and why do job preferences affect results of explicit searches?

Comment: Could you please explain how job preferences affect results of explicit searching? I can reproduce OPs problem.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't do it. I still have the same problem. I have the problem even when I access the site from a browser that is not logged in.

Comment: I just tried the search and I only see two jobs within 100km of Massachusetts.  So definitely not fixed.

Comment: @SpikeWilliams It appears there is another issue. We're on it.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo Job preferences can override advertising region restrictions, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327749/1370722

Comment: Is there any update on this? Its still broken.

Comment: @SpikeWilliams there's a fix in the works; some crazy geo-coding issues on the backend :/

Comment: @SpikeWilliams Sorry for the outrageously long delay. This went *much* deeper than we initially thought. Things should be running smooth now. If not, please feel free to email careers@stackoverflow.com with a reference to this question. Thanks again for your report!